# CentOS 7 rpc_pipefs mount options not persistent after reboot

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, systemd

I'm trying to mount rpc_pipefs with a nodev option. Initially, I tried doing this by editing the /etc/fstab file and adding an entry for it.

Tried:

`sunrpc   /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs     rpc_pipefs  rw,nodev,relatime   0 0`

Also:

`rpc_pipefs   /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs     rpc_pipefs  rw,nodev,relatime   0 0`

Both failed to work. (no errors reported but the changes would not take after running mount -a or rebooting)

This is when I did more reading/research and discovered that the file was being mounted using systemd.

I can add the desired mount option by editing the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount` file and adding the following:

```
Options=nodev
```

When I run the following, the partition/fs is mounted with the nodev option. However, It does not survive a reboot.

```
[~] systemctl daemon-reload
[~] systemctl restart var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
[~] systemctl enable var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
```

Also tried appending the following to the mount file but it made no difference:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

Environment:

```
[user@ip-10-0-0-0 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
 CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
[user@ip-10-0-0-0 ~]$ uname -r
 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
[user@ip-10-0-0-0 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so posting here. Can you post the output of `systemctl status var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount`?

I just added the `Option=nodev` as advised [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3400121). I rebooted and can see the nodev option too.

```
[root@centoserv ~]# systemctl status var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
● var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount - RPC Pipe File System
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Sun 2018-11-04 23:29:31 IST; 2min 34s ago
    Where: /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
     What: sunrpc
  Process: 597 ExecMount=/bin/mount sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs -t rpc_pipefs -o nodev (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 04 23:29:31 centoserv systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
Nov 04 23:29:31 centoserv systemd[1]: Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[root@centoserv ~]#
[root@centoserv ~]# mount|grep rpc
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,nodev,relatime)
[root@centoserv ~]#
[root@centoserv ~]# grep rpc /proc/mounts
sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: The 'as advised here'  link is behind a paywall. Any details on what actually need to be done?